# Combinatorics problem- ordered triple

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can you form ordered triples (a,b,c) where $a <b$ and $a <c$? A,b and c are numbers from 1 to 100.

I tried it by sorting it by the value of a. If a=1 there are 99 choices for b and 99 for c so that is 99×99 and so on until a=99 and there is only one choice for b and c. So that would be a sum of squares from 1 to 99. I am wondering why this approach is wrong

I do realise that the easier way to solve it is by dividing it into two cases: when a,b and c are all inequal and when b=c so that would be (100*99*98)/(3!)*2 +(100*99)/(2!), but I don't understand what's wrong with the first approach.

Comment: Please check to make sure your question is complete.

Comment: The question is:In how many different ways can you form ordered triples (a,b,c) where a <b and a <c? A,b and c are numbers from 1 to 100.

Comment: I don't understand it keeps cutting my question it only shows the first line

Comment: I put in some dollar signs around the math and it displayed better.  Please move your comments into the question itself - otherwise this question is likely to be put on hold.

Comment: I get the same answer both ways, perhaps you have a calculation error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum that you describe with the second method is
$$
\frac{100\cdot 99\cdot 98}{3}+\frac{100\cdot 99}{2}=328,350.
$$

The sum of the first $n$ squares is
$$
\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$
Plugging in $99$ for $n$ gives $328,350$.

Both of your answers are right.